# Escoger filas de Gridview en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Estoy extrayendo información a un `GridView` pero veo que son bastante campos que yo no deseo.

¿Cómo se podría hacer para solo escoger las filas que yo deseo?

Adjunto la imagen de `GridView` y todo lo que me sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que jalo a mi `GridView`.

```
dtorequest.Monto = Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporteCredito.Text);//Convert.ToDecimal(1900.00);
dtorequest.MontoCapitalFijo = 0;
dtorequest.MontoTIR2 = 10000;
dtorequest.MontoTIR3 = 0;
int somestring = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Value);
dtorequest.NumeroCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, 2));// 12;
dtorequest.Oficina = 5;
dtorequest.Periodicidad = 30;
dtorequest.PeriodicidadCapital = 0;
dtorequest.PeriodicidadInteres = 0;
dtorequest.PeriodosGracia = 0;
dtorequest.Plazo = 360;
dtorequest.PorcentajeMinimoCuoton = 0;
dtorequest.RedondeoHacia = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoRedondeo.Arriba;

dtorequest.Tasa = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTEA.Text);//40;
dtorequest.TasaInicialObjetivo = 0;
dtorequest.TipoGracia = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoGracia.GraciaCapital;
dtorequest.TipoTabla = "CUOTFIJA";

listadtodividendo = tabla.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(dtorequest).ToList();

GridView1.DataSource = listadtodividendo;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Por ejemplo, de todo eso yo solo quiero que se muestre como la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿`dtorequest` de qué tipo es?

Comment: @Flxtr es un servicio que le pongo ese nombre pero no se que tipo sera:

  ServiceReference1.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest dtorequest = new ServiceReference1.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para que puedan esconder una fila de un gridview
tiene que agregar una nueva propiedad llamada RowCreated y realizar este codigo indicando el numero de fila que quieren esconder:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente en tu GridView vas a poner la caracteristica de

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Monto" HeaderText="Monto" />
</columns>
```

Así sucesivamente vas creando BoundField dependiendo las columnas que quieres crear. OJO el "DataField" se pone el nombre del dato

Comment: @Ermesto Emmanuel mi hermano ese gridview se crea desde un servicio web

Comment: Una disculpa, por mi error